# Insert Date and time when a Cell is Modified in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, power-automate, office-scripts

I have a report sheet, and each time a cell is modified on that sheet, I want a given cell to input the time the modification took place and for it not to change.

For example, when A1 is modified, B1 should reflect the date and time A1 was modified, B1 should always show the date and time when the initial modification took place and should not change, while c1 will always show the most recent modification date.

I have been able to get this done with some basic Excel code

```
=IF(R2<>"",IF(P2="",NOW(),P2),"")
```

and also, with VBA macros

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyDataRng As Range

Set MyDataRng = Range("A2:A10")

If Intersect (Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next

If Target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now

 
Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now


End Sub
```

My problem with the first solution is that although I wrote the formula using the Excel app, it requires iterative calculations and that doesn't run on Excel online, which is where the Excel sheet is to be used.

The other solution with the VBA doesn't also help as VBA codes don't run on Excel online. I was wondering if there's an alternative to go around this problem in order to make the solution work on Excel Online.

P.S I thought Power Automate might help, but I cannot find any suitable material that solves my problem using Power Automate.

Comment: One option is to use office scripts instead of VBA. Another option is to default the file to open on the user's desktop application instead of on the web, so that VBA can be used.

Comment: Checkout https://excelweez.com/how-to-timestamp-in-excel-when-cell-changes/ might be what you require.  Would have to alter to test if :initial modification"/creation is empty to avoid changing.  Haven't dived into the example could also explore onchange events.

Comment: The example Excel workset appears to have what you require https://excelweez.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Excel-timestamp-practice-sheet.xlsx

Comment: Events aren't an option in Office Scripts.  There's really no option because PowerAutomate isn't targeted enough.  You're stuck unfortunately.